# Dense Optical Flow in JavaCV (DualTVL1)

Tags: c++, opencv, javacv, opticalflow

I have implemented dense optical flow to compute the velocity of every pixel in c++ previously. This example helps me a lot (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tvl1_optical_flow.cpp). Now I want to convert my code to java but i couldn’t find a an equivalent JavaCV function for createOptFlow_DualTVL1(). Could anybody help me with that? It would be great if it is with example.

my code in c++ using OpenCV is like this:

```
Mat New_Previous_Gray (holds the previous image)
Mat New_Current_Gray (holds the current image)
Mat_<Point2f> Optical_Flow;

Ptr<DenseOpticalFlow> tvl1 = createOptFlow_DualTVL1();                 //This two lines is the want i want to change to JavaCV
tvl1->calc(New_Previous_Gray, New_Current_Gray, Optical_Flow);     //This two lines is the want i want to change to JavaCV

double Pxl_Distance[Optical_Flow.rows][Optical_Flow.rows]; //will hold the velocity for every pixel 
for(int y = 0; y < Optical_Flow.cols; y++)
{
for(int x = 0; x < Optical_Flow.rows; x++)
{
const Point2f& flow_xy = Optical_Flow.at<Point2f>(x, y);
int Vel_x = flow_xy.x;
int Vel_y = flow_xy.y;
Pxl_Distance = sqrt(double(((abs(Vel_x) * abs(Vel_x)) + (abs(Vel_y) * abs(Vel_y)))));
Pxl_Distance[x][y] = Pxl_Distance;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

so far i have been working on this below is the code i came up with to compute the optical flow can anyone tell me i'm doing it right

```
IplImage pFrameGray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(pFront),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
IplImage cFrameGray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(pFront),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
cvConvertImage(pFront, pFrameGray, CV_CVTIMG_FLIP);
cvConvertImage(cFront, cFrameGray, CV_CVTIMG_FLIP);
IplImage Optical_Flow  = cvCreateImage( cvSize(pFrameGray.width(),pFrameGray.height()), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 2 );
DenseOpticalFlow tvl1 = createOptFlow_DualTVL1();
tvl1.calc(pFrameGray, cFrameGray, Optical_Flow);
```

and if this is the right was how can i get the optical values from Optical_Flow(IplImage).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public void TestOF()
{
   IplImage pFrame = cvLoadImage("/sdcard//DCIM/Camera/Frame-1.jpg");
   IplImage cFrame = cvLoadImage("/sdcard//DCIM/Camera/Frame-2.jpg");
   IplImage pGray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(pFrame),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
   IplImage cGray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(cFrame),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
   cvConvertImage(pFrame, pGray, IPL_DEPTH_32F);
   cvConvertImage(cFrame, cGray, IPL_DEPTH_32F);
   IplImage Optical_Flow  = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(pGray), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 2 );
   DenseOpticalFlow tvl1 = createOptFlow_DualTVL1();
   tvl1.calc(pGray, cGray, Optical_Flow);
   FloatBuffer buffer = Optical_Flow.getFloatBuffer(); 
   CvMat OF  = cvCreateMat( pGray.height(),pGray.width(), CV_32FC1);
   int pixelVelocity =0;
   int xVelocity = 0;
   int yVelocity = 0;
   int bufferIndex = 0;
   for(int y =0; y< pGray.height(); y++)
   {
      for(int x = 0; x < pGray.width() ;x++)
      {
         xVelocity = (int)buffer.get(bufferIndex);
         yVelocity = (int)buffer.get(bufferIndex+1);
         pixelVelocity = (int)Math.sqrt((double)(xVelocity*xVelocity +             yVelocity*yVelocity));
         OF.put(y, x, pixelVelocity);
     }
   }
   IplImage temp = OF.asIplImage();
   cvSaveImage("/sdcard//DCIM/Camera/OF.jpg",temp);
}
```

This code will calculate the optical flow for every pixel using DenseOpticalFlow between two images (Frame-1 & Frame-2) and put the velocity of every pixel to anther image (OF) in their coordinate.
cheers.